# How to insert custom query into MySQL based on a radioButton value?

Tags: c#, mysql

**Current GUI:**

I have 2 radiobuttons with the following options; `12 Months` and `Manually set review date`.

If the `dateAuto` is checked:

[image]

If the date `dateManual` is checked (Brings up a manual date picker):

[image]

**Goal:**

I am trying to build a custom query based on which radio button is clicked.

- If `dateAuto` is checked, insert value into MySQL as `NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH;`.
- If `dateManual` is checked, insert values into MySQL as **selected value from datepicker**

**This is how I currently trying to achieve my goal:**

```
//Get date of review date
public string ReviewDate = "";

void getDate()
{
    //12 Months
    if (dateAuto.Checked)
    {
        ReviewDate = "DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)";
    }
    //Manual Date
    if (dateManual.Checked)
    {
        string manualDate = reviewDate.Value.Date.ToString();
        ReviewDate = $"(str_to_date({manualDate}, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'))";
    }
}
```

**Current MySQL query:**

```
//Get date
getDate();

//Execute command
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO files (reviewDate) VALUES (@date)"

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", ReviewDate.ToString());
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myTrans.Commit();
```

This code does not work because, `ReviewDate.ToString()` shows me this error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from `string` to `MySQLDBType`
```

**Also tried:**

I have tried this line of code too `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", ReviewDate);`

But I get a different error when executing the code:

[image]

**Question:**

Is something wrong with my query? Or Im I using C# parameters wrong?

**Edit:**

Comment: Use a datetime variable and make the @date parameter of date type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

**Function to get date:**

```
//Get date of review date
void getDate()
{
    //12 Months
    if (dateYes.Checked)
    {
        reviewDate.Value = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(+12);
    }
    //Manual Date
    if (dateNo.Checked)
    {
        reviewDate.Value = reviewDate.Value;
    }
}
```

**MySQL insert code**

```
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO files (reviewDate) VALUES (@date)"

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", reviewDate.Value);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myTrans.Commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `DateTime`, converting its value to a string, and adding a string to datetime funcion as a string parameter to the function. That has two problems:

- MySQL handles `(str_to_date(01/01/2020, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'))` as a single string parameter, it does not try to convert it to the datetime (despite you should escape the datetime). <-- This is causing your error
- There is no need to such complexity, you could directly use the DateTime and pass it to `myCommand`

If you wanted to use a string parameter (I would recomend against it) you could do:

```
INSERT INTO files (reviewDate) VALUES (str_to_date(@date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'))
```

But you should really consider not doing the unnecesary conversions, this should work:

```cs
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO files (reviewDate) VALUES (@date)"

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", reviewDate.Value.Date);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myTrans.Commit();
```

Comment: I have updated my question - hopefully it makes more sense

Comment: @LV98 Have you understood my answer? Have you tried my second suggestion?

Comment: `String does not contain a definition for Value and no accessible extension method Value accepting a first argument of type string could be found`

Comment: No, in my second code fragment I did not declare a new string, That is why `reviewDate` has a lowercase "r". What I did is use the Date property of the datetime picker directly.

Comment: I see - but this will insert `manual` date .. but if I choose to use `NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH`? there is not mention of that?

Comment: In that case there would be no need to add a parameter, and what should change is: a) There would be no and b) The insert should be similar to `INSERT INTO files (reviewDate) VALUES (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH))`

Comment: I think I know what you mean by using `reviewDate`... I'll answer a question.. and let me know if that what you meant.